# JAXB - Controlling element names for lists inside wrapper class

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a class wrapping up a list and some other attribute and in another class I have multiple instances of the wrapper type. I know that we can control the name of elements by adding XmlElement annotation to whichever element we need. Is there any way to specify the element name corresponding to the contents of a wrapper type from wherever the wrapper type is used?

For instance, the wrapper class looks like

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Wrapper {

  @XmlElement(name = "name")
  private List<String> names;
  private String comment;

  //Getters and setters

}
```

And the wrapper is used as

```
private Wrapper employeeNames;
private Wrapper departmentNames;
private Wrapper someOtherNames;
```

Can I in someway annotate these fields, so that I would have XML formed as

```
<employeeNames>
  <employeeName>ABC DEF</employeeName>
  <employeeName>PQR STU</employeeName>
  <employeeName>ABC</employeeName>
</employeeNames>
<departmentNames>
  <departmentName>PQR</departmentName>
  <departmentName>PQR STU</departmentName>
  <departmentName>MNO</departmentName>
</departmentNames>
```

I know that if don't have the wrapper and directly use the lists, I can have `@XmlElementWrapper` and `@XmlElement` annotations used to build the XML like this.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Wrapper {
    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "employeeName", type = EmployeeName.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "departmentName", type = DepartmentName.class),
    })
    private List<Name> names;
    private String comment;

    public void setNames(List<Name> names) {
        this.names = names;
    }
}
```

and then EmployeeName and DepartmentName something like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EmployeeName implements Name {
    @XmlValue
    private String name;

    public EmployeeName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

They both implement an interface that doesn't do much:

```
public interface Name {  }
```

I changed your `List<String>` to `List<Name>` in your wrapper, because the marshaling would have problem to differentiate between employeeName and departmentName if they both were of type String.

Comment: This would force to create separate types for each usage of the wrapper (and also replacing String with another type). This won't be a good approach in my case as the JAXB annotated classes mentioned are not exclusively for XML generation.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to mind is that instead of `@XmlElement` you could use `@XmlElementRef` like

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "name")
private List<JAXBElement<String>> names;
```

Then you could specify the desired element name in each of the elements of `names`:

```
wrapper.names.add(new QName("departmentName"), String.class, "PQR");
```

Comment: I was thinking of writing some adapter that would do this. Changing the type in the wrapper can't be done.